# Extract Data between specific fields of text

Tags: parsing

In a Python code, after opening a textfile, how can I have it extracts data in a specific body of text. Would I use a regex expression to record all data within the body of the text file?

Example of Textfile:

Enable Movies:

```
        Channel 1: News

        Channel 2: Entertainment
```

Disable Movies

Enable TV Shows

```
        Channel 1: News

        Channel 2: Entertainment
```

Disable TV Shows

My goal for the code is only to extract News and Entertainment from Enable TV Shows to Disable TV Shows and store it into a list without storing the data from Enable Movies to Disable Movies.

Desired Output from print category:

[News]

Instead of,

[News,News]

Example snippet code of why I have duplicate data:

```
    category = []
    with open("Data.txt") as f1:
        for line in f1:
                x = re.search(r'(?<=(Channel 1:\s)\w+',line)
                if x:
                    category.append(x.group())
        print category
```

Is there someway that you can store everything in the list once you see the title Enable TV Shows and stop storing items in the list once you see Disable TV Shoes?

Comment: 1. Do you need this done in a specific programming language? 2. Please provide the exact output you are looking for, your description is vague.

Comment: Python Sorry: Updating the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get unique values you may convert the list to a set `myset = set(mylist)`  so

```
myset = set(category)
print myset
```

for clearnees i put my other answer here as it wasnt displaying ok in the comments:

```
    with open('file.txt') as input_data:
      for line in input_data: 
       if line.strip() == 'Enable TV Shows': 
      break 
     for line in input_data:
      if line.strip() == 'Disable TV shows': 
       break
     print line or store in list
```

Comment: That is useful, but would I be able to pull data between the Enable and Disable title of TV Shows only?

Is there someway that you can store everything in the list once you see the title Enable TV Shows and stop storing items in the list once you see Disable TV Shoes?

Comment: Well assuming all the text files are formatted the same, you could read from the line number that has Enable TV Shows and stop when it reaches the line Disable TV Shows

Comment: `with open('file.txt') as input_data:
    
   for line in input_data:
        if line.strip() == 'Enable TV Shows': 
            break
   
   for line in input_data:  
        if line.strip() == 'Disable TV shows':
            break                                                           print line or store in array`

Answer (score 0):

for entertainment `\d: (E.*)` for news `:(.*)C` [image]

[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Ill take it into account, but the author of the question edited the original question at first he asked for a regexp